# Fullcalendar eventLimit in agendaWeek , agendaDay

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

i tried to use eventLimit function in agendaWeek and agendaDay but it shows "+3 more" in only allday cells, not in Day cells. I tried to use

```
eventLimit: {
    'agenda': 6, // adjust to 6 only for agendaWeek/agendaDay
    'default': true // give the default value to other views
}
```

but still same , is there any ways to show it on day cells or show similar string? :)
Thank you.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? The `eventLimit` only makes sense in all-day cells. When you are viewing events that are not all-day, they will become overlapped and are always showed. Please provides an example of what you want.

Comment: Hello , @milz Thank you for your response all i am trying to do is show +more link in agendaDays time cell please see following link https://imageshack.com/i/p4pUx6DNp

Comment: @Boldbayar Can you create a jsfiddle where the problem arises where you feel you want the "+X more" link? Here's a vanilla fiddle to start from: http://jsfiddle.net/arshaw/3E8nk/

Comment: @RichardHermanson i want +X more in Time cells like - ( +3 more in 6am-10am) not in day cell

Comment: I'm guessing you dislike this behaviour? http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/562/ Can you describe how you want it to work?

Comment: @RichardHermanson Hello i want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/3E8nk/565/

Comment: i used event to show my problem , in my problem it should be something like eventLimit thanks :)

Comment: You still haven't specified much about the behaviour (when is this supposed to happen for example?). At the moment, nothing about this makes sense. Moreover, your modifications would probably involve rewriting the source.

Answer (score 1):

Finally new version provides background event , it is all i wanted http://fullcalendar.io/download/